# Mootools cross domain, YQL proxy

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools, cross-domain, jsonp

I've been trying to make ajax cross domain scripting with YQL as proxy. It works great, but can i somehow change the data format?

Im trying to extend the JSONP class like this:
http://fragged.org/cross-domain-ajax-calls-via-yql-as-proxy-and-mootools-jsonp_1028.html

And im getting data as text/html, but would like it to be as xml.
In standard Mootools:

```
new Request({
```

method: 'get',
   url: this.options.url,
   onComplete: function(text, xml) {

Here i can fetch the text AND xml.

**UPDATED:**
My solution: Instead of making request with Mootools class, just use the callback function that YQL allows.

Comment: Do i need to convert my serverscript to json somehow? It is a service that echo file contents which is in xml format. But then i cant use this cross domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: Instead of making request with Mootools class, just use the callback function that YQL allows.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net) for this - it allows you to do cross-domain ajax by using only a small html file hosted on the remote domain.
You can check out this example at http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/xhr.html